# Why can variables in Kotlin be overridden, while in Java, they cannot?

Tags: java, kotlin, variables, jvm, overriding

In java, variables cannot be overridden but can only be hidden. Whereas in kotlin, we can override the variables.

Though they both run on JVM, why is this difference?
Is it because the variables in kotlin aren't really being overridden but only the default getters are being overridden? Is my understanding correct?

**Kotlin code:**

```
open class Animal {
    open var name: String = "Animal"
}

class Dog : Animal() {
    override var name: String = "Dog"
}

fun main() {
    val animal: Animal = Dog()
    println(animal.name) // Output: Dog
}
```

**Java code:**

```
class Animal {
    String name = "Animal";
}

class Dog extends Animal {
    String name = "Dog";
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal animal = new Dog();
        System.out.println(animal.name); // Output: Animal
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to edit this question and include some code showing precisely what you mean by 'variables can be overridden'. The JLS explains what 'override' means, and defines that term __solely__ for methods. Hence, the sentence "variables cannot be overridden" is a bit like "satisfaction is blue" - it's english, but as a sentence, the concepts just don't even apply to each other.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Hey, I apologize for that, I'm new to this. Is my edited question clear now? So you're saying kotlin isn't actually overriding the variable rather it's just overriding the getter method?

Comment: Those aren’t variables. They’re properties. Yes, you are overriding the getter. The backing variable of the superclass’s property still exists conceptually. Your subclass can still call the superclass’s property implementation to access it.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that `String name = "Animal";` in Java is not the same as `open var name: String = "Animal"` in Kotlin. That's why the former construction is called *field*, and the latter is called *property*.

By default, non-private *var* properties in Kotlin are effectively a private field with non-private getter and setter on the Java level (you can see it after clicking *Tools -> Kotlin -> Show Kotlin Bytecode* and then *Decompile*, as on the screenshot below).

[image]

So, you effectively override its getter and setter, and not the field itself. If you create a *Java* class `Cat`, you'll only be able to override the corresponding methods.

Comment: Properties only have a backing field if you initialize them or they're `lateinit`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thank you for the addition!

As far as I remember, the only case of a property without initialization (besides lateinit) is a `val` followed by `get()`, right? That turns into just a method that starts with 'get' on the Java level.

And I meant to imply that the rule in my answer is not absolute (e.g., not applicable to properties annotated with 'JvmField'), that's why I wrote 'By default'.

Comment: You can also have a `var` property with no initialization (and therefore no backing field) if it’s followed by `get` and `set`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Ah, yes, exactly. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Firstly the behaviour between the Kotlin code and the Java code is the same at run time, so the only difference is in the coding style.

Kotlin forces you to state that you are overriding the property (as stated in a comment, in reality the getter), whereas Java doesn't. That's the only difference; Kotlin is being stricter by making it obvious that you are overriding something (e.g. making things open and using the override keyword) whereas in Java it's a bit of a free for all, Wild West approach.

In the Java there is the OverRide annotation, but it's not mandatory.